# Number format for wp_count_posts()

Tags: posts, formatting

I'm trying to format my post my total post count in the header of my site. I have the number in there but would like it to format with the commas eg 1,500 not 1500. I know this is probably really basic but I'm still learning.. any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

functions.php

```
function wpb_total_posts() { 
$total = wp_count_posts()->publish;
echo '' . $total;
}
```

Header.php

```
<?php wpb_total_posts(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP [function `number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
function wpb_total_posts() { 
    $total = wp_count_posts()->publish;
    echo number_format( 
        $total, // your number
        0,      // number of decimal points
        '.',    // decimal point separator
        ','     // thousands separator
    );
}
```

Or, because you are using the default values anyway, you can shorten the function to:

```
function wpb_total_posts() { 
    echo number_format( wp_count_posts()->publish );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much legend!! Perfect!